# Using delete [] operator to de-allocate memory of data member in class

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I have the following data members in my `Array` class.

`private:
    Point* m_data;
    int m_array_size;`

 I want to implement a copy constructor for this class as follows:

`Array(const Array &a)`

Inside the implementation. I have the following.

```
Array::Array(const Array &a) : m_array_size(a.m_array_size) {
    delete[] m_data;
    m_data = new Point[m_array_size]

    for(int i = 0; i < m_array_size; i++) {
        m_data[i] = a.m_data[i];
    }
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault error which I suspect is due to the `delete[]` operation. However, I don't see what i'm doing wrong here. I'm simply deallocating memory associated with `m_data` and reallocating new memory to it.

I am not sure if the following is relevant, but since i'm using a custom object as a data member inside the Array class, here is the overloaded assignment operator from that class.

```
Point& Point::operator = (const Point &source) {

    if(this == &source) return *this;

    m_x = source.m_x;
    m_y = source.m_y;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: This is a constructor, it is the first thing that runs when your object starts to exist.  Because your object is brand new, **there is no memory attached to `m_data` that needs to be freed**

Comment: I would strongly advise using `std::vector<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, if you need a dynamically-sized array, so that you won't have to roll your own implementation, and keep track of all the bugs and inefficiencies that are prone with DIY data structures. Your problem would go away, and be less likely to show up again, if you did that instead, and your code would probably perform better overall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your copy constructor attempts to `delete[]` the `m_data` member without ever having initialized it. It's undefined behaviour to pass an uninitialized pointer to `delete` or `delete[]`. Most other uses of uninitialized pointer values are also UB.

Since this is the constructor, it's wholly unnecessary to `delete[]` anything. Simply remove that line and it should work.

On the other hand, in the copy-assignment operator, you must remember to `delete[]` the existing array.